# Using two models in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to use several models in one view, but I don't know how.

Of these two models:

```
@model DetailsViewModel
@model IEnumerable<Product>
```

I want to use it in a view

Comment: This is a clear scenario where you need a new viewmodel, one that fits the current view's needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a view model class that includes both of them

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public DetailsViewModel DetailsViewModel {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products {get; set;}
}
```

View

```
@model ProductViewModel
```

Controller action

```
....
var model = new ProductViewModel
                {
                    DetailsViewModel= ...your code,
                    Products=...your code
                };
return View(model);
```